# How to setDate of JDateChooser to NULL or "0000-00-00"

Tags: java, netbeans, jdatechooser

This is my code, but it is not working.

```
if (Start.getDate() == null && End.getDate() == null) {
     Start.setDate(null);
     End.setDate(null);
}
```

So, how can i set the date of `JDateChooser` to null or `"0000-00-00"` ?

In my program the user can click on the Table to view the information of each row. and each row is connected to the database so the Start(JDateChooser) & End(JDateChooser) has a value on the database. the problem is when the user clicked on the row which has a value for Start & End the value successfully showed on JDateChoosers based on the database BUT when the user click again on another row which is the row dont have a value for Start & End the JDatechoosers is not making a NULL or ""(Empty)? it stil have a value.

Comment: Please post your more code that how you made your JDateChooser....

Comment: Im Using JFrame form
so that is Drag & drop

Comment: why you want to set null to date?

Comment: from netbeans if yes then what plugin you are using ???

Comment: Im using JCalendar.jar

Comment: In my program the user can click on the Table to view the information of each row. and each row is connected to the database so the Start(JDateChooser) & End(JDateChooser) has a value on the database. the problem is when the user clicked on the row which has a value for Start & End the value successfully showed on JDateChoosers based on the database BUT when the user click again on another row which is the row dont have a value for Start & End the JDatechoosers is not making a NULL or ""(Empty)? it stil have a value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can set your date to `0000-00-00`. Cos the `minSelectableDate` of `jDateChooser` `is Jan 1, 0001`

Comment: how about to set it in null?